# Pandas pct change from initial value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to find the pct_change of `Dew_P Temp (C)` from the initial value of -3.9. I want the pct_change in a new column.

Source here:

```
weather = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jvns/pandas-cookbook/master/data/weather_2012.csv')
weather[weather.columns[:4]].head()


Date/Time        Temp (C)   Dew_P Temp (C)  Rel Hum (%)
0   2012-01-01   -1.8       -3.9             86
1   2012-01-01   -1.8       -3.7             87
2   2012-01-01   -1.8       -3.4             89
3   2012-01-01   -1.5       -3.2             88
4   2012-01-01   -1.5       -3.3             88
```

I have tried variations of this for loop (even going as far as adding an index shown here) but to no avail:

```
for index, dew_point in weather['Dew_P Temp (C)'].iteritems():
    new = weather['Dew_P Temp (C)'][index]
    old = weather['Dew_P Temp (C)'][0]
    pct_diff = (new-old)/old*100
    weather['pct_diff'] = pct_diff
```

I think the problem is the `weather['pct_diff']`, it doesn't take the `new` it takes the last value of the data frame and subtracts it from `old`

So its always (2.1-3.9)/3.9*100 thus my percent change is always -46%.

The end result I want is this:

```
Date/Time        Temp (C)   Dew_P Temp (C)  Rel Hum (%)   pct_diff
0   2012-01-01   -1.8       -3.9             86           0.00%
1   2012-01-01   -1.8       -3.7             87           5.12%
2   2012-01-01   -1.8       -3.4             89           12.82%
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `iat` to access the scalar value (e.g. `iat[0]` accesses the first value in the series).

```
df = weather
df['pct_diff'] = df['Dew_P Temp (C)'] / df['Dew_P Temp (C)'].iat[0] - 1
```

Comment: IMO, your solution is much better!

Comment: That is a really elegant solution... I'm wondering if there is a why to do it with a for loop since that makes the most sense to me.

Comment: I agree, this is most succint

Comment: @dyao This is a vectorized solution for the column that is both succinct to write and also very efficient. It will be much faster than a for loop.

Comment: @Alexander I  don't doubt its much faster; I only ask because coming from Excel, for loops make much more sense to me than vectorized solutions. To me it looks like magic, whereas in a for loop solution every step is explicit.

Comment: @dyao
Using Pandas, the idea is to limit/prevent for loops. Since pandas is very good at doing this all kinds of mathematics, reshaping, shifting, etc. data frames. In some cases if it's really looks impossible. The .apply() function can help you in combination with another python feature called: lambda. Things like:
`print df['Temp (C)'].apply(lambda x: x**2)`. This will square the all values in 1 call.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [88]: ((weather['Dew Point Temp (C)'] - weather.ix[0, 'Dew Point Temp (C)']).abs() / weather.ix[0, 'Dew Point Temp (C)']).abs() * 100
Out[88]:
0         0.000000
1         5.128205
2        12.820513
3        17.948718
4        15.384615
5        15.384615
6        20.512821
7         7.692308
8         7.692308
9        20.512821
```

Answer (score 4):

I find this more graceful

```
weather['Dew_P Temp (C)'].pct_change().fillna(0).add(1).cumprod().sub(1)

0    0.000000
1   -0.051282
2   -0.128205
3   -0.179487
4   -0.153846
Name: Dew_P Temp (C), dtype: float64
```

---

To get your expected output with absolute values

```
weather['pct_diff'] = weather['Dew_P Temp (C)'].pct_change().fillna(0).add(1).cumprod().sub(1).abs()
weather
```

[image]